# kafka flink connection error shows NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-flink

new error appeared when i change from flinkkafkaconsumer09 to flinkkafkaconsumer
Flink code:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import java.util.Properties;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ReadFromKafka {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create execution environment
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test-consumer-group");


    DataStream<String> stream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>("test4", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));

    stream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

      @Override
      public String map(String value) throws Exception {
        return "Stream Value: " + value;
      }
    }).print();

    env.execute();
  }


}
```

ERROR:
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.executeJobBlocking(MiniCluster.java:626)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1507)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1489)
    at ReadFromKafka.main(ReadFromKafka.java:33)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dataartisans</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>kafkaex</name>
  <description>this is flink kafka example</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but Flink doesn't like jobs that don't produce any results. Try adding a sink -- e.g., `stream.print();`.

Comment: not that problem actually i reduced the code here only i added print() function in eclipse.

Comment: Can't tell what's wrong. Please share more info: imports, dependencies, complete error report (some details are cropped off the right side).

Comment: added fully along with pom and error

Comment: kafka 2.12 flink 1.9.1

Comment: Thanks got it values are streaming.but i have another doubt?how can i get key and value from above code because above code displays value only not the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flink-connector-kafka_2.12` isn't compatible with `FlinkKafkaConsumer09`.

`flink-connector-kafka_2.12` is a "universal" kafka connector, compiled for use with Scala 2.12. This universal connector can be used with any version of Kafka from 0.11.0 onward.

`FlinkKafkaConsumer09` is for use with Kafka 0.9.x. If your Kafka broker is running Kafka 0.9.x, then you will need `flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11` or `flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.12`, depending on which version of Scala you want.

On the other hand, if your Kafka broker is running a recent version of Kafka (0.11.0 or newer), then stick with `flink-connector-kafka_2.12` and use `FlinkKafkaConsumer` instead of `FlinkKafkaConsumer09`.

See [the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#apache-kafka-connector) for more info.

Comment: on changing flinkkafkaconsumer another error shows up.